# How to Marshal / Unmarshal Golang OAuth2.0 token with custom properties

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, customization

I have an OAuth 2.0 token with custom properties that I want to marshal and unmarshal between JSON and a `golang.org/x/oauth2.Token` struct:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Token

I can load custom properties into the `Token` using `WithExtra()` but I can't marshal the token back to a JSON representation with all the custom properties.

Here's what I've tried.

Using an [example OAuth 2.0 token with custom properties from Apigee](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/security/oauth/customizing-access-tokens):

```json
{
  "issued_at" : "1372170159093",
  "application_name" : "ccd1803b-b557-4520-bd62-ddd3abf8e501",
  "scope" : "READ",
  "status" : "approved",
  "api_product_list" : "[Product1,Product2]",
  "api_product_list_json" : ["Product1", "Product2"],
  "expires_in" : "3599", //--in seconds
  "developer.email" : "joe@weathersample.com",
  "organization_id" : "0",
  "refresh_token" : "82XMXgDyHTpFyXOaApj8C2AGIPnN2IZe",
  "client_id" : "deAVedE0W9Z9U35PAMaAJYphBJCGdrND",
  "access_token" : "shTUmeI1geSKin0TODcGLXBNe9vp",
  "organization_name" : "apifactory",
  "refresh_count" : "0"
}
```

I would need to load the data twice into the `Token` struct, once, with a `json.Unmarshal` and second by loading a `map[string]interface{}` using `WithExtra()`.

- Using only `WithExtra` won't load the standard properties
- Using only the `json.Unmarshal(data, token)` won't load the custom properties

> Note: the code can be steamlined with a single `json.Unmarshal` but I left both because it's easier to read.

Here's the code:

```golang
package main

import(
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

const rawToken = `{
    "issued_at" : "1372170159093",
    "application_name" : "ccd1803b-b557-4520-bd62-ddd3abf8e501",
    "scope" : "READ",
    "status" : "approved",
    "api_product_list" : "[Product1,Product2]",
    "api_product_list_json" : ["Product1", "Product2"],
    "expires_in" : "3599",
    "developer.email" : "joe@weathersample.com",
    "organization_id" : "0",
    "refresh_token" : "82XMXgDyHTpFyXOaApj8C2AGIPnN2IZe",
    "client_id" : "deAVedE0W9Z9U35PAMaAJYphBJCGdrND",
    "access_token" : "shTUmeI1geSKin0TODcGLXBNe9vp",
    "organization_name" : "apifactory",
    "refresh_count" : "0"
}`

func ParseToken(rawToken []byte) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    tok := &oauth2.Token{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(rawToken, tok)
    if err != nil {
        return tok, err
    }
    msi := map[string]interface{}{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(rawToken, &msi)
    if err != nil {
        return tok, err
    }
    return tok.WithExtra(msi), nil
}

func main() {
    tok, err := ParseToken([]byte(rawToken))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("application_name [%s]", tok.Extra("application_name").(string))
}
```

With this approach, if I marshal the token to JSON, I only get the `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `expiry` properties. Standard [OAuth 2.0 properties](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1) like `scope` and custom properties are not included.

My preference is to have this done with the `oauth2.Token` struct so the token can be created by `oauth.Config` such as using the `oauth2.Config.Exchange()` function. Otherwise, a new OAuth 2.0 package may be needed. Some libraries I use that can handle custom data include [`github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go) for JWT and [`github.com/getkin/kin-openapi`](https://github.com/getkin/kin-openapi) for OpenAPI specifications.

Questions:

1. Is there an easier way to marshal a JSON token to a `oauth2.Token`?
2. Once custom properties are loaded into a `oauth2.Token`, is there a way to marshal it back to JSON with the custom properties?
3. I'm using `golang.org/x/oauth2` now, but is there another OAuth 2 library that has more handling of custom properties?

Answer (score 0):

Is such an option possible in your case?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "log"
)

type ExtendedToken struct {
    oauth2.Token
    IssuedAt           string   `json:"issued_at,omitempty"`
    ApplicationName    string   `json:"application_name,omitempty"`
    Scope              string   `json:"scope,omitempty"`
    Status             string   `json:"status,omitempty"`
    ApiProductList     string   `json:"api_product_list,omitempty"`
    ApiProductListJson []string `json:"api_product_list_json,omitempty"`
    ExpiresIn          string   `json:"expires_in,omitempty"`
    DeveloperEmail     string   `json:"developer.email,omitempty"`
    OrganizationId     string   `json:"organization_id,omitempty"`
    ClientId           string   `json:"client_id,omitempty"`
    OrganizationName   string   `json:"organization_name,omitempty"`
    RefreshCount       string   `json:"refresh_count,omitempty"`
}

func ParseExtendedToken(rawToken []byte) (*ExtendedToken, error) {
    tok := &ExtendedToken{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(rawToken, tok)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return tok, nil
}

func main() {
    tok, err := ParseExtendedToken([]byte(rawToken))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("application_name [%s]\n", tok.ApplicationName)

    back, _ := json.Marshal(tok)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", back)
}
```

Comment: That's a potential custom approach, but I'd like to avoide this since it's necessary for many OAuth providers. The ideal solution would be fore this to be implemented by `golang.org/x/oauth2` so the token an be created by `oauth2.Config`. A fallback solution is ot create a new, more flexible OAuth library like `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go` for JWT and `github.com/getkin/kin-openapi` for OpenAPI specifications. Both `jwt-go` and `kin-openapi` have generic ways to handle custom properties. I've added this, with links, to the question.